# How to make different elements under <tr> behave differently when hover over <tr> in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to make different changes to different elements under `<tr>`.

For example, I want to:

1. change background color of `<tr>` to black
2. change black `<p>` text color to white
3. change red `<p>` text color to blue

Here is the HTML code :

```
<tr class="trhl">               
    <td class = "td1">
        <p class="p1">Hello</p>
        <p class="p2">Enrique!</p>
    </td>
    <td class = "td2">
        <p class="p3">Hi</p>
        <p class="p4">Madonna</p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Following is the CSS code for the above :

```
p.p2 {
    color:#c04848;
}
p.p3{
    color:#c04848;
}
```

And I want to implement the changes on `<tr>` hover as following:

```
tr.trh1:hover {
    background-color: black;
}
tr.trh1:hover .p1, .p4{             
    color: white;
}
tr.trh1:hover .p2, .p3{             
    color: blue;
}
```

How to do the above changes using CSS?

Comment: Just to be clear, you're trying to make those CSS changes on hover?

Comment: Please check the spell mistake for 'L' and '1' for trhl or trh1. It seems you use L in html and 1 in css.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your big issue is that the class on the table row is `.trhl` and you have put `.trh1` (tr-h-One).

```css
p.p2 {
  color: #c04848;
}
p.p3 {
  color: #c04848;
}
.trhl:hover {
  background-color: black;
}
.trhl:hover .p1,
.trhl:hover .p4 {
  color: white;
}
.trhl:hover .p2,
.trhl:hover .p3 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="trhl">
    <td class="td1">
      <p class="p1">Hello</p>
      <p class="p2">Enrique!</p>
    </td>
    <td class="td2">
      <p class="p3">CSS3 is the ticket</p>
      <p class="p4">Madonna</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I am now able to change the color of the text, but the background color of the table row .trh1 is not changing to black

Comment: you need to declare those styles then. The class you have applied to the HTML is `TRHL` not `TRH1`

Answer (score -1):

Why set `tr.trh1:hover`? You should set hover on the `<p>` element by class

```
tr .p1:hover,.p4:hover {   color:white; }

tr .p2:hover, .p3:hover {  color: blue; }
```

Comment: I want to change the background color of <tr> on hover as well as change the color of the text

Answer (score -1):

```css
.trh1:hover {
    background-color: black;
}
.trh1:hover .p1,
.trh1:hover .p4 {
    color: white;
}
.trh1:hover .p2,
.trh1:hover .p3 {
    color: blue;
}
```

This will work for you

Comment: Please provide more details to your answer as this post has been found in low quality post. Code only and 'try this' answers are discouraged as it doesn't provide any searchable content and why people should 'try this'.